# How to use array_contains with 2 columns in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have an issue , I want to check if an array of string contains string present in another column . I am currently using below code which is giving an error.

```
.withColumn("is_designer_present", when(array_contains(col("list_of_designers"),$"dept_resp"),1).otherwise(0))
```

error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName dept_resp
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:77)
```

Comment: why don't you use a udf function?

Comment: like?   do you have any udf handy with you?

Comment: I have answered below :) hope it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can write a `udf` function to get your job done

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def stringContains = udf((array: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String], str: String) => array.contains(str))
df.withColumn("is_designer_present", when(stringContains(col("list_of_designers"), $"dept_resp"),1).otherwise(0))
```

You can return appropriate value from `udf` function itself so that you don't have to use `when` function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def stringContains = udf((array: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String], str: String) => if (array.contains(str)) 1 else 0)
df.withColumn("is_designer_present", stringContains(col("list_of_designers"), $"dept_resp"))
```

Comment: my pleasure @user3222101, but udfs are not recommended when you have other inbuilt functions in hand. I couldn't find other inbuilt functions meet your requirement and thus I suggested udf function. :)

Answer (score 4):

With Spark 1.6 you can wrap your `array_contains()` as a string into the `expr()` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr

.withColumn("is_designer_present",
    when(expr("array_contains(list_of_designers, dept_resp)"), 1).otherwise(0))
```

This form of `array_contains` inside the `expr` can accept a column as the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a somewhat old question, but I found myself in a similar predicament, and found the following solution. It uses Spark native functions (so it doesn't suffer from UDF related performance regressions, and it does not rely in string expressions (which are hard to maintain).

```scala
def array_contains_column(arrayColumn: Column, valueColumn: Column): Column = {
    new Column(ArrayContains(arrayColumn.expr, valueColumn.expr))
}

// ...

df.withColumn(
    "is_designer_present",
    when(
        array_contains_column(col("list_of_designers"),col("dept_resp")),
        1
    ).otherwise(0)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it without UDFs using explode.

```
.withColumn("exploCol", explode($"dept_resp"))
.withColumn("aux", when($"exploCol" === col("list_of_designers"), 1).otherwise(0))
.drop("exploCol")
.groupBy($"dep_rest") //all cols except aux
  .agg(sum($"aux") as "result")
```

And there you go, if result > 0 then "dept_rest" contains the value.